# Getting "DebugType" parameter is not supported by the "XamlCTask" task error on building my Xamarin ios project

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.ios, xamarin.android

I get these errors when building my Xamarin.ios project,

**The "XamlCTask" task could not be initialized with its input parameters.**

and

**The "DebugType" parameter is not supported by the "XamlCTask" task. Verify the parameter exists on the task, and it is a settable public instance property.**

How can I fix this.

Comment: Please try the solutions mentioned [here](https://forums.xamarin.com/discussion/95724/xamarin-forms-2-3-4-247-update-project-wont-build).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Open the .csproj in a text editor. Then remove,

```
<Error Condition="!Exists(...
```

within,

```
<Target> Name="EnsureNuGetPackageBuildImports" BeforeTargets="PrepareForBuild">    
    //
    <Error Condition="!Exists('...
    //
</Target>
```

that is related to raising this error.

Then rebuild the project, it should work.

Comment: I recommend check and consolidate your Xamarin Nuget packages to the latest stable version instead of removing this safety check.

Comment: Open the .csproj in a text editor. Then remove...   It works for me.

Answer (score 5):

I had the same error but with xamarin Debugging on an android device. I would recommend that you check your `Nuget` packages? I had different versions of `Xamarin.Forms` which caused conflicts. Obviously you need to make sure that they are all on equal versions of forms.

Check and Consolidate your Xamarin Nuget packages to the latest stable version.

Answer (score 0):

1) make sure all your projects reference the same Xamarin Version
2) In every project, delete the content on the bin and obj folders 
3) rebuild